# How to add a year to today's date and default it to the preceding working day

Tags: php

If I want to default a date to the next working day I am using the following:

```
<?php
    echo(date('d/m/Y',strtotime('+1 Weekdays')));
?>
```

For example: If a user is adding an item on a Friday it is given a default of the following Monday - the next working day.

I have to create a schedule of events with a start and end date. The end date needs to 1 year in the future on the preceding working day.

For example: If a user adds a schedule that has a start day of Wednesday and the same date in a years time happens to be a Sunday, then the end date needs to default to the previous Friday - the preceding working day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
<?php
    echo(date(date('d/m/Y',strtotime('+1 year')),strtotime('-1 Weekdays')));
?>
```

Comment: You can do this in one shot with `strtotime('+1 year -1 weekdays')`

Comment: can you add this as an answer please?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add one year to today's date then check the day of the week, if it is 'Sat' or 'Sun' subtract one weekday. [The PHP `DateTime` object](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime) makes this easy with the `format()` and `modify()` methods.

```php
$inOneYear = new DateTime('+1 year');
if(in_array($inOneYear->format('D'), ['Sat', 'Sun'])){
    $inOneYear->modify('-1 weekday');
}
echo $inOneYear->format('D, d/m/Y');
```

In all these cases:

- today (Thursday, Dec. 1st, 2022)
- tomorrow (Friday, Dec. 2nd, 2022)
- the next day (Saturday, Dec. 3rd, 2022)

the above will output:

```
Fri, 01/12/2023
```

Answer (score 0):

The `strtotime()` function and the `DateTime` constructor both take stacking relative values, and will process them in order, so you can do things like:

```
$when = strtotime('now +1 year -1 weekdays');
$when = new DateTime('now +1 year -1 weekdays');
```